# QueryBuider get parameters for Dao.queryRaw

Tags: ormlite, query-builder

I'm using QueryBuider to create raw query, but I need to fill parameters to raw query manually.

Properties 'from' and 'to' are filled two times. One in 'where' section of QueryBuider, and one in queryRaw method as parameters.
Method StatementBuilder.prepareStatementString() returns query string with "?" for substitution.

Is there any way to get these parameters directly from QueryBuider instance?

For example, imagine a new method in ormlite - StatementBuilder.getPreparedStatementParameters();

```
QueryBuilder<AccountableItemEntity, Long> accountableItemQb = accountableItemDao.queryBuilder();

QueryBuilder<AccountingEntryEntity, Long> accountingEntryQb = accountingEntryDao.queryBuilder();
accountingEntryQb.where().eq(
    AccountingEntryEntity.ACCOUNTING_ENTRY_STATE_FIELD_NAME, 
    AccountingEntryStateEnum.CREATED);
accountingEntryQb.join(accountableItemQb);

QueryBuilder<AccountingTransactionEntity, Long> accountingTransactionQb =
    accountingTransactionDao.queryBuilder();
accountingTransactionQb.selectRaw("ACCOUNTINGENTRYENTITY.TITLE, " +
        "ACCOUNTINGENTRYENTITY.ACCOUNTABLE_ITEM_ID, " +
        "SUM(ACCOUNTINGENTRYENTITY.COUNT), " +
        "SUM(ACCOUNTINGENTRYENTITY.COUNT * CONVERT(ACCOUNTINGENTRYENTITY.PRICEAMOUNT,DECIMAL(20, 2)))");
accountingTransactionQb.join(accountingEntryQb);
accountingTransactionQb.where().eq(
        AccountingTransactionEntity.ACCOUNTING_TRANSACTION_STATE_FIELD_NAME,
        AccountingTransactionStateEnum.PRINTED)
    .and().between(AccountingTransactionEntity.CREATE_TIME_FIELD_NAME, from, to);
accountingTransactionQb.groupByRaw(
    "ACCOUNTINGENTRYENTITY.ACCOUNTABLE_ITEM_ID, ACCOUNTINGENTRYENTITY.TITLE");

String query = accountingTransactionQb.prepareStatementString();

accountingTransactionQb.prepare().getStatement();

Timestamp fromTimestamp = new Timestamp(from.getTime());
Timestamp toTimestamp = new Timestamp(to.getTime());

//TODO: get parameters from accountingTransactionQb
GenericRawResults<Object[]> genericRawResults =
    accountingEntryDao.queryRaw(query, new DataType[] { DataType.STRING,
        DataType.LONG, DataType.LONG, DataType.BIG_DECIMAL },
        fromTimestamp.toString(), toTimestamp.toString());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there any way to get these parameters directly from QueryBuider instance?

Yes, there is a way.  You need to subclass `QueryBuilder` and then you can use the `appendStatementString(...)` method.  You provide the `argList` which then can be used to get the list of arguments.

```
protected void appendStatementString(StringBuilder sb,
        List<ArgumentHolder> argList) throws SQLException {
    appendStatementStart(sb, argList);
    appendWhereStatement(sb, argList, true);
    appendStatementEnd(sb, argList);
}
```

> For example, imagine a new method in ormlite - StatementBuilder.getPreparedStatementParameters();

Good idea.  I've made the [following changes](https://github.com/j256/ormlite-core/commit/83a92bd727985295915fd8ed7db6d9a1f23cf87e) to the Github repo.

```
public StatementInfo prepareStatementInfo() throws SQLException {
    List<ArgumentHolder> argList = new ArrayList<ArgumentHolder>();
    String statement = buildStatementString(argList);
    return new StatementInfo(statement, argList);
}
...
public static class StatementInfo {
    private final String statement;
    private final List<ArgumentHolder> argList;
    ...
```

The feature will be in version 4.46.  You can build a release from current trunk if you don't want to wait for that release.